# Option to join Abyss no longer displays

Tags: starcraft

After the recent updates to the ICCup Launcher I no longer see the option to join the abys server option only the regular servers are displayed: west east asia and Europe.

Im doing everything the way I always did but the option does not show up.

I also tried searching for the solution elsewhere I've seen that other people are having similar problem in this [post](http://www.iccup.com/starcraft/community/thread/500398.html). I tried following the suggested solution of downloading the iCCup_WarCraft_3_Reg.zip file but it didnt help me at all.

Comment: I already reinstalled the launcher, restarted computer and closed down all other programs including the launcher before trying to get the option back. This did not yield any results so please dont post it in the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some research showed that other people had this problem as well.

Apparently, this is a bug that is caused by the current iteration of the ICCup launcher.

Unlike previous versions, the launcher no longer re-adds the registry entry for ICCup every time you start it. As a result, anytime you access a regular battle.net gateway (such as USEast) Blizzard removes the ICCup entry and you have to go back to ICCup.com and get the registry entry.

If you are interested in doing this manually, the following steps should suffice just know that anytime you manually edit your registry, there can be dire consequences if you do it wrong.

> Manual Registry Edit:
>
> 1. type 'regedit' into the start menu's 'Run' dialog or directly into the search for windows Vista and beyond.

2. navigate to "HKEY_CURRENT_USER -> Software -> Battle.net -> Configuration"
3. open the Battle.net Gateways key
4. add the following lines to the bottom of the file then save and close it. (Note: the format is always gateway address, time difference and then server name.)

   > > sc.theabyss.ru
   > >
   > > 0
   > >
   > > iCCup

Upon restart, you should have iCCup at the bottom again. 
However this change will revert anytime you connect to a Blizzard gateway.

credit to: sGs.DNH

The original, source of this, including another option in case this fix doesn't work can be found at:

> http://www.iccup.com/community/thread/503519.html

Comment: Thanks for expanding your answer.  I'd recommend removing the bit after the link, as going, "If this doesn't help, check there instead of here" runs counter to how Arqade works; we'd like authoritative answers provided here.

Comment: Psst....we're not a forum! :P

Comment: By the time I'm done, the list of edits will be longer than the post :P
I promise I'll get the hang of this soon.

Comment: No worries. :)  But you also don't need the edit lines.  If you want to expand your post, feel free to add in the steps found at that link.  That'll help your answer.

Comment: Finally something that works. Im wondering if you know how to make this solution more permanent every time i enter a gateway I need to go to regedit and redo the whole thing. I was trying to make the reg file read only but i cant even find it on my computer.

Comment: Honestly, if this truly is Blizzard replacing the file every time, I don't see a way past this. Making it read only might actually cause more problems and affect your connectivity to Blizzard's servers. I wouldn't risk that were I you.

Comment: Registry files just change something in your registry; making the file itself read only won't help, because the file itself isn't read by the game.  If Blizzard is truly resetting these settings, I'm not sure we should be helping bypass the protections Blizzard has put into place.

Comment: @superdemongob I am really happy to get it working again I just wish there was a permanent solution. There must be a way even if I have to freeze some memory addresses to keep them from changing the gateway. Either way i shall award you the bounty before time runs out.

Comment: @Xitcod13: thank you good sir, that is very kind. I'm going to look into permanent fixes but whether this is just me being a coward, I wouldn't mess with the registry in the way you're suggesting. Windows doesn't like when you extensively play with the registry.

Comment: @Xitcod13 After you changed the registry setting export it to a .reg file. Then before you run the game just add the settings from the file

Comment: @Josefvz and how do i exactly add the setting from the file?

Comment: @Xitcod13 |Right-Click -> Merge

Comment: @Josefvz Ty i think it works now :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add that there are two ways to stop other servers from overwriting your server list in the registry.

1. Modify your existing registry key

   - HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Battle.net\Configuration\Battle.net gateways - Modify the first line and set it to a high number like 99999
2. Create a new registry key to override the other one. Right click -> New -> Multi-String Value

   - name it "Override Battle.net gateways" and paste the server information from Battle.net gateways